# Entity Framework, how to make this more generic to write less code

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

So, I am writing a program, and getting my data using EF 6.

Basically, I though the simplest approach would be to have one class like this:

```
  public class DataRetriever
{
    public List<TEntity> GetAll<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        using (var Db = new Entity())
        {
            return Db.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
        }
    }

}
```

So then, you care start creating other classes on the basis of specifying which data you want to be collected. So say I have a list of carnival rides and one method is to get a single ride or something. SO then I would have the following:

```
   public class SelectedRide
{
    int RideId { get; set; }
    string RideName { get; set; }
    string DomValue { get; set; }

    public SelectedRide(DataRetriever Retriever)
    {
        var Records = Retriever.GetAll<vwRideList>();
        var Record = from x in Records
                     where x.RideId == RideId
                     select x;
        RideName = Record.Single().RideName;
        DomValue = Record.Single().DomValue;

    }
}
```

Ride ID being an identity.

So then one could say that if another class like say we had multiple parks where rides were, could be `public class SelectedPark` it would have the same logic, but in the `Retriever.GetAll<vwParkList>();` The ride list is now the park list. And so on.

I can't tell if this is quickly going to get out of hand if I say had 50 separate types of retrieving that needed to be done. Granted, I won't as I know the total scope of this program, but WHAT IF.

I've seen stuff like the repo pattern as well, but I can't tell if that's somewhat of a waste of time or not. I can't tell what I am getting out of it. This seemed to keep it generic enough that I am not writing the context in a million different places.

Comment: A repo pattern with Get, GetById, Insert, Update, Delete seems to be sufficient for the most generic and common of CRUD operations.GetById, in particular, can be generically applicable as long as the entity classes conform to a basic interface (such as, the ID field is named "ID," which is controllable in your models).

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Gotcha, I guess then I need to read more about the pattern then, because I still get lost how if I still have to end up mapping back to my properties then at some point, somewhere, aren't I not still ending up a similar problem regarding trying to stay generic, and then in the end, I still am struggling seeing the savings. Could be naive, again I need to go back and look at the pattern.

Comment: @MZawg, the repository pattern in conjuction with EntityFramework is an anti pattern,  EntityFramework is already a repostiory,  what you really need is just a simple Generic Service base which handles your CRUD Operations, Additionally, anytime I see ` return Db.Set<TEntity>().ToList();` this is a big nono,  This will cause you to materialize all of the data before filtering.

Comment: @johnny5  if it’s not a big deal, could you answer the question with an example of what you would do to avoid the ‘Db.set’. I think that would probably answer the question. :)

Comment: @MZawg I only have proprietary code,  but I can give you a run down.  Have a base service which handles CRUD.  If you need to obtain another entity e.g if a park has benches in it.  Then you create another service for benches etc.  If you need to filter you parks which seems somewhat of the issue your having.  Then you have to manually implement those functions on the class OR you can be lazy like me and just add a dynamic filtering modules like [ODATA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/)

Comment: @johnny5 Reading your link now. Sounds like that is the better option, though. But one thing about your first suggestion. When you say "manually implement those functions on the class", I am not 100% following. You mean in the same place that I currently about doing the `return Db.Set<TEntity>().ToList();` , correct?

Comment: Yeah you either have to use some sort of dynamic filtering or you'll end up having to write a function which filters the data certain fields, e.g the user wants to find all parks that have a pond etc

Comment: @johnny5  I think that is a good enough of an answer for me tbh. Learning DB.set isn’t really a good idea, is sending me in the appropriate direction I’d say.

Comment: @johnny5, so it sounds like you really never get away from 1 single "grab some data based on a certain TEntity"  and return it, similiar to my example. Otherwise I end up getting every piece of data everytime this way. So in practice it might be less code but its way more strain on data processing?